# Empty Windows Service can't be run (timeout everytime)

Tags: c#, windows-services

This is my whole service

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{


    public Worker()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I register it with sc.exe create and I run it with sc.exe start. I am running it with admin access in cmd. I keep getting this error:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your app to be run as a windows service, first need to add this package:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`

And in the `Program.cs`:

```cs
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = ".NET Joke Service";
});

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

Here is a very good guideline for creating windows service by Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

Comment: Thank u so much. it fixed the issue. could u plz explain a little what was wrong with my process as I registered the service in commandline?

Comment: @Masoud Not sure but I think the problem was with your ``.exe`` location and the OS couldn't find and run the app, you can check ``Event Viewer``  under ``Windows Log -> Application`` to see a detailed error.